# Does having apply_filters in the middle of an array make a difference?

Tags: plugins, filters

I'm trying to extend a plugin for Wordpress that loads several scripts through an array in 1 function in the footer. I have separate scripts in a separate plugin that I'm wanting to run along these. Here's an example of the array:

```
$scripts['keyboard-keypad'] = WC_POS()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/register/qty-keyboard-keypad.js';
$scripts['keyboard-addons'] = WC_POS()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/register/qty-keyboard-addons.js';
$scripts = apply_filters('wc_pos_enqueue_scripts', $scripts);
$scripts['wc-pos-functions'] = WC_POS()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/register/functions.js';
$scripts['handlebars-helpers'] = WC_POS()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/register/handlebars/handlebars.helpers.js';

...

foreach ($scripts as $name => $script) {
        wp_enqueue_script($name, $script, array('jquery'), time(), true);
    }

global $wp_scripts;

foreach ($wp_scripts->registered as $script) {
        if (strpos($script->src, 'http:') === 0 || strpos($script->src, 'https:') === 0) {
            $manifest .= str_replace(' ', '%20', $script->src) . "\n";
        } else {
            $manifest .= site_url() . str_replace(' ', '%20', $script->src) . "\n";
        }
    }
```

There's probably 20+ entries to the $scripts before this apply_filters, and 6 or so after.

In my extension plugin, I'm trying to filter this array:

```
add_filter( 'wc_pos_enqueue_scripts', 'wmediadesi_qz_js', 20 );

function wmediadesi_qz_js( $scripts ) {

        $scripts['wc-pos-print-wms'] = 'https://directurl.com/1.js';
        $scripts['wc-pos-print-wmws'] = 'https://directurl.com/2.js';
        $scripts['wc-pos-print-wmwms'] = 'https://directurl.com/3.js';
        return $scripts;
    }
```

But this is causing some of the scripts to not be defined if my plugin is loaded. Specifically, 'handlebars' (which comes after the apply_filters) becomes undefined. Now if I modify the original plugin to put the apply_filters at the end of the array, other items in the array much further up the stack become undefined.

Am I missing something in how I'm using the apply_filter? Or am I missing something with the foreach loops?

For note: if I modify the original plugin by adding in the needed .js files and modify this array, everything works well.

Comment: is the first foreach right? whats that `</script>';`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end. Moving too quickly - that whole foreach is a bit messed up.